# Firebase Firestore Query in Android Kotlin

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio, google-cloud-firestore, android-mvvm

I have Firestore DB structure like this. In this app, I'm able to display all Time slots of Lynda to the Customer.

**Customer Collection**

[image]

**User Timeslots Collection**

[image]

**User Collection**

[image]

**User Collections Appointment**

[image]

**The query for getting all Timeslots of Lynda1102**

```
 // get all time slots
override fun getAllSlots(): MutableLiveData<List<Slots>> {
    remoteDB.collection("Timeslots").whereEqualTo("id", "Lynda1102")
        .addSnapshotListener { querySnapshot, e ->

            //  check if null
            if (e != null) {
                Timber.e("Listen failed. $e")
                savedAllTimeSlots.value = null
            }

            val saveTimeSlots: MutableList<Slots> = mutableListOf()
            for (doc in querySnapshot!!) {
                val slotItem = doc.toObject(RemoteTimeSlots::class.java).apply { id = doc.id }
                    .mapToTimeSlots()
                saveTimeSlots.add(slotItem)
            }

            // Post value 
            savedAllTimeSlots.value = saveTimeSlots

        }

    return savedAllTimeSlots
}
```

**I'm Observing data in Activity**

```
    // observe for service changes
    viewModel.getAllSlots().observe(this, androidx.lifecycle.Observer {
        timeSlotsAdapter.differ.submitList(it)

    })
```

How to query & show available slots for customer on a particular date.

Ex- On 13-05-2020 Lynda has a total of three slots. The customer booked slot no - 2.

So now the other customers will have to see only the remaining two slots(slot1 & slot3) on 13-05-2020.

If no slots booked on any date. it should show all three slots. So user can create appointment.

Answer (score 0):

Add a field inside time slots as `isAvailable:true`. Whenever a user selects a timeslot, mark the key as false and query out the timeslots who have isAvailable as true.